# Link in bootstrap tab not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to load pages when using the boostrap tab navigation, but it doesn't work. I tried to override the default action by creating a class names `preventDefault` and using jQuery, but it still doesn't work.

My code looks like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">

  <!--About section-->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#profile" class = "preventDefault" aria-controls="account" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" class = "preventDefault" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" ng-view>
            information
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--About section-->
```

```
<!--jQuery-->
<script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.preventDefault').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
</script>
```

My goal is to use ngRoute with Angular, so I can't use the standard tab system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the target id eg `id="profile"` in the tab-pane

```
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" ng-view id="profile">
        information
      </div>
```

Comment: I want to load partials with angular and ngRoute, and therefore can't use this "standard" way of doing it. I need to be able to do some routing with the links.